# Is it possible to call Https without encryption?

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

From my understanding, each browser implement tls/ssl themself, which mean when user open a https website from a browser, the browser is responsible for encrypt the request.

So is it possible to make a browser or any other type of client that doesn't implement tls/ssl and therefore will make https without encryption? And if yes, then how ?

Comment: HTTPS without TLS/SSL is HTTP

Answer (score 2):

> ... client that doesn't implement tls/ssl and therefore will make https without encryption?

HTTPS is HTTP inside a TLS connection. This means a client which does not implement SSL/TLS will not be able to make a HTTPS connection in the first place by the very definition of what HTTPS is.

It might in theory be possible though that TLS is used without encryption, i.e. only with authentication and integrity check. Up to TLS version 1.2 there were the NULL ciphers which made this possible. In practice no sane server will implement this. If the client still tries to use such cipher the TLS handshake will fail since there is no common cipher between client and server.

See also [Unencrypted SSL protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930108/unencrypted-ssl-protocol).